# Reset page number in Sub report for crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I am using page number N of M in  Main report 'Page footer' and I added the Sub report in 'Report footer'(not linked to main report). I want to Reset the Page number in Main report with change of group ( group #2 in bottom pic) in sub report.
the page number usually is resetted according to Group #1 in main report however when subreport started the page numbers are continuous even with change in group # 2. Is there any way to reset page number in such cases?

[Screengrab of Mainreport and Subreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXPDh.jpg))

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the section expert of group #2 footer section.
2. Check "Reset Page Number After".